# How to add an image to an object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am creating an object `client` which I add to an array called `clientlist`, and besides adding the name of the user, the type of user and description, I need to add an image to this object using an image of the array of images `imagelist` listed above. Any ideas?

```
var clientlist = {};
var imagelist = ["image1.jpg","image2.jpg","image3.jpg"];

function myFunction(){

var client = {};

var user = $("#username").val();
var type = $("#type").val();
var description = $("#description").val();

client["user"] = user;
client["type"] = type;
client["description"] = description;

clientlist[clientlist.length] = client;

$("#message").html("Client created");

}
```

Comment: JavaScript Objects don't have a `.length`. If you want the entries to be inserted in order, then you'll want to use an Array (`var clientlist = [];`) and [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Comment: how those images relate to a certain user?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I want each object to contain a different image, as if it were the avatar of each client.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I use the `.length` to add each client to a new position in the array `clientlist`. The first client in position `0`, the second in position `1` and so on.

Comment: @Gonzalo `clientlist` isn't an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). It's a plain [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) and its `.length` will be `undefined`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski My mistake, I used `{ }` instead of `[ ]`. Clientlist is supposed to be an array.

Comment: @Gonzalo, if `imagelist` is intended as values in dropdown list, you should use appropriate selector to get a selected image from dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you would set the first image to the avatar of the client:

```
client["avatar"] = imagelist[0]; // The client's avatar will be the first image of the list.
```

So then client.avatar would be `"image1.jpg"`

If you want it to be a dropdown box, you would have this HTML:

```
<select>
    <option value="0">Image 1</option>
    <option value="1">Image 2</option>
    <option value="2">Image 3</option>
</select>
```

To update client.avatar, just use this JavaScript:

```
var avatar = document.getElementById('avatar');
client["avatar"] = imagelist[avatar.options[avatar.selectedIndex].value];
```

Comment: @MysteryBlockHed What if you pick the image from a dropdown list?. How would you write it so the image that I choose from the dropdown list is added to the object?

Comment: @Gonzalo I just added a way to do that :)

Comment: @MysteryBlockhed Sorry I forgot, it worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like below.

```
var imagelist = ["image1.jpg","image2.jpg","image3.jpg"];
var client;

var user = $("#username").val();
var type = $("#type").val();
var description = $("#description").val();

for (var i = 0, len = imagelist.length; i < len; i++) {
    (function(i){ 
      var client = new Object();
      client["user"] = user;
      client["type"] = type;
      client["description"] = description;
      client["yourAvatar"] = imagelist[i];
    })(i)
}
```